# moving an array element to a register assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86

My assignment is to find the smallest letter in the array using assembly embedded into C. I am not sure how to access each element of the array. I tried googling and I found out that some people are doing the following:

mov ecx, arrayOfLetters

and then increment ecx to access each element. Is that right or what I wrote so is correct?

please help, I am confused.

```
    char findMinLetter( char arrayOfLetters[], int arraySize )
{
    char min;

    __asm{
        push eax
        push ebx
        push ecx
        push edx
        mov dl, 0x7f        // initialize DL


        xor ebx, ebx //EBX started off as 0

        //moves letters from array to registers
        mov ecx, arrayOfLetters[ebx]
        mov edx, arrayOfLetters[ebx+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that 'arrayOfLetters' as passed to your subroutine is a pointer.

To access data (one byte at a time) from pointer (in ecx) in assembler, use:

```
mov al, [ecx]
mov al, [ecx+1]
...  or ...

mov al, [ecx]
inc ecx
mov al, [ecx]
```

The next issue is how local variables are accessed: there are two main styles used and both of them use *stack*.

```
mov ecx, _localvariable_ ; this translates to either

mov ecx, [ebp + offset]  ; style (1) or
mov ecx, [esp + offset]  ; style (2)
```

If there was a assembler supporting instruction mov ecx, _localvariable [+1], that would most likely convert to:

```
mov ecx, [ebp + offset + 1]
```

And this would not access the char array[], but just some arbitrary byte in the stack.

Comment: Also mov ecx, _localvar_ + offset + [ebx] would be perfectly legal combination (depending on the assembler). That would convert to mov ecx, [offset_X + ebp + ebx]; which is a valid addressing mode, but wouldn't do the intended thing